# flex-wrap doesn't center items when passing to next line

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

When all columns fit in one line the `space-around` works fine and the text is centered within the column.

However, when each column is set to `width:33.333%`, then it jumps to a new line but isn't centered horizontally.

You can see here:
https://jsfiddle.net/f2yb72c9/1/

**CSS**

```
ul{
  list-style:none;
  padding:0;
}
.row-flex--footer {
    align-content: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

footer .column {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}
@media (min-width: 868px) {
  footer .column {
    flex: 1 1 33.333%;
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<footer>

<div class="row-flex--footer">
          <div class="column">
            <nav>
              <h4 class="hl--list footer__hl">Company</h4>
              <ul>
                <li> <a class="footer__link">About us</a></li>
                <li><a class="footer__link">Careers</a></li>
                <li> <a class="footer__link">News</a></li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
          </div>
          <div class="column">
            <nav> 
              <h4 class="hl--list footer__hl">Surgeons</h4>
              <ul>
                <li> <a class="footer__link">3D Business Manager</a></li>
                <li><a class="footer__link">Plans &amp; Pricing</a></li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
          </div>
          <div class="column">         
            <nav> 
              <h4 class="hl--list footer__hl">Patients  </h4>
              <ul>
                <li> <a class="footer__link">Find a Crisalix surgeon</a></li>
                <li><a class="footer__link">Community</a></li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
          </div>
          <div class="column">            
            <nav>
              <h4 class="hl--list footer__hl">Support </h4>
              <ul>
                <li> <a class="footer__link">Surgeon Help Center</a></li>
                <li><a class="footer__link">Patient Help Center</a></li>
                <li><a class="footer__link">Surgeon Help Center</a></li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
          </div>
          <div class="column">          
            <nav>
              <h4 class="hl--list footer__hl">Legal</h4>
              <ul>
                <li> <a class="footer__link">Universal terms</a></li>
                <li><a class="footer__link">Privacy policy</a></li>
                <li><a class="footer__link">Security statements</a></li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
          </div>
          <div class="column">           
            <nav>
              <h4 class="hl--list footer__hl">Social</h4>
              <ul>
                <li> <a class="footer__link">Facebook</a></li>
                <li><a class="footer__link">Twitter</a></li>
                <li><a class="footer__link">Youtube</a></li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
          </div>
        </div>
      </footer>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're expecting to see. If I delete the fourth column, the two remaining items on the bottom center themselves. So what are you expecting to see that's different?